# Changing arrow padding bootstrap carousel - angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I can't figure out how to change the padding/spacing between the arrows in angular bootstrap carousel

I want the spacing to be smaller on each size of the arrows:

[image: I want the spacing to be smaller on each size of the arrows]

I want the spacing to be smaller on each size of the arrows, So the black spacing is getting more space.

My code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
      <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <app-nyheter></app-nyheter>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
      <img [src]="images[1]" alt="Random second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
      <img [src]="images[2]" alt="Random third slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
</div>
```

css:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-caption {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 95%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ngb-carousel arrows are styled by css classes `carousel-control-prev` and `carousel-control-next` wich determine the position of the arrows in an absolute way. Override these classes in your css with letf and right values you want:

```
.carousel-control-prev {
    left: 'whatyouwant'px;
}

.carousel-control-next {
    right: 'whatyouwant'px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that before, but nothing happens. So I dont understand why I cant override those CSS values?

Comment: Have you try to put the css in your styles.css at the root of your angular  app ?

Comment: I tried it now, but still no change in the arrow space

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the spacing by adding it to another class, but now the problem is that I cant change the position of the arrow itself.

```
.carousel-caption {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 95%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check what version of n-bootstrap are you using, e.g. for ng-bootstrap 12.0.0 you can use (in styles.css)

```
.carousel-control-prev {
  width: 1.5rem;
}

.carousel-control-next {
  width: 1.5rem;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

(a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sdkfzm?file=src%2Fstyles.css))